# GCP can't SSH to DataLab after changing VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I upgraded the VM on a DataLab and tried to connect through the command line using `datalab connect`.  I received the error repeated every few seconds:

^[Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
Connection broken
Attempting to reconnect...
Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/

I tried resetting the SSH key using

```
sudo gcloud compute config-ssh
```

but get the same error and

```
gcloud compute ssh <new-vm-id>
```

but got the same error.  I checked the Firewall Rules and the relevant ones are as follows:

[image: Fire wall Rules]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The new VM needs to be turned on in VM Instances.  This sounds basic, but you need to wait until the seemingly endless repetition of the error message has finished before turning on the VM and trying again.  It's still quite an embarrassing oversight.

Comment: You can accept your answer to let know people you found the issue.Thanks